# How to create a Regexp To find all strings in JS files (or JSON)

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I am trying to extract all strings in js files.
(to use the regexp in sublime text "search in all files")

For example, this is a one of the text files:

```
a='string1'
b='string2'
c="string3"
alert("string\"4")
alert('string\'5')
```

So, I have this RegExp:

```
/('.*?')|(".*?")/
```

And I found This:

```
['string1'].['string2',"string3"]
```

But I need also:

```
["string4","string5"]
```

How I do that?

(I am searching for RegExp solution - One RegExp sentence)

One more thing: The best solution is, if it also possibile to ignore all JS comments, inside the files. (To not extract JS strings, in comments)

Thank you.

Comment: `alert('string\'5")` is not a correct string since its not properly closed, is it a typo?

Comment: Fixed. Mean that:     alert('string\'5')

Comment: Then `["string4","string5"]` is wrong as they're actually `["string\"4","string\'5"]`.

Comment: I don't use ST, but I quickly googled for "sublime text structural search" and the first hit was [grasp](http://www.graspjs.com/blog/2013/12/17/grasp-0.2.0-released/) which seems to do what you're looking for (and much more).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try the below regex.

```
(['"])(?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*?\1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gZ3mU2/1)

- `(['"])` captures `'` or `"` quotes and stored it into group index 1.
- `(?:\\\1|(?!\1).)` This allows escaped character (*character which was captured by the group index 1*). OR not of the captured character zero or more times.
- `\1` And it must be ended by the character which was captured by the group index 1.
- It also matches the strings like `"string'5'"` or `'string"5"'`